# How to list array from state in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just started looking at reactjs and trying to display a list of items from state, this is a fragment of my main component:

```
const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <AddButton

      addToList={() => store.dispatch(
        {
          type: 'ADDTEXT',
          payload: {
            text: 'this is a text'
          }
        }
      )}
    />

    <List items="store.getState()"></List>
  </div>

  ,
  rootEl
)
```

I was hoping to inject the state into the list which is an array.
List looks like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Item from './Item'

const List = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map(item =>
      <Item
        key={item.id}
        {...item}

      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
//


export default List
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function
```

The complete code sits in:https://github.com/dimitri-a/counter_react/examples/counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't pass `items` as a string `store.getState()`. Try this :

```
<List items={store.getState()}></List>
```